# Disable TabBar's Back Capability

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a detail view that has a navigation bar and a tab bar. I can easily hide/disable the back button in the navigation bar, but I need to prevent the user from going back to the list view by pressing the tab bar. Any help would be great!

This is how I am disabling the back button in the navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the detail view is pushed do this:

```
detailView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

That way the tab bar will be hidden when the detail view is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guess this is how your storyboard looks.

[image]

But really, you should do it like this.

[image]